# How to use Dispatcher or BackroundWorker with custom StatusBar control on WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, backgroundworker, dispatcher

In my application I realized a custom statusbar control. It has progressbar, statusTextBox etc. Other modules could get the instance of that class with MEF, and bind their data in his elements with methods and properties. The problem is that the View of my statusbar updates only after some operation has finished.
Here is a code example:

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public IconManagerModel(IStatusBar statusBar)
{
    StatusBar = statusBar;
}

public void SomeMethod()
{    
    for(...)
    {
        //I tried to use Dispatcher but it didn't help. View updates after method has finished
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,  
            delegate()
            {
                StatusBar.SetProgress(amountComleted,total)
            }
        );

        // ...
    }
}
```

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to run `SomeMethod()` on another thread, then call back onto the `Dispatcher` to update the progress. Really, if the custom progress bar is hooked up to some UI element, then the implementation should handle the calling back onto the UI thread.

You may want something a little like:

```
public IconManagerModel(IStatusBar statusBar)
{
    StatusBar = statusBar;

    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(SomeMethod));
    thread.Start();
}
```

`SomeMethod()` will now be running on a different thread, so if you update the progress on the UI thread then you should see the results you desire.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answer by [slade](https://stackoverflow.com/users/308012/slade), I'd also suggest using DispatcherPriority.Render if you want the message pump to process the message immediately. Play around with Invoke (synchronous) and BeginInvoke (asynchronous). The former will force the update immediately, however will block your processing work. The latter will update when the message pump is free and is generally recommended.

Either way your background work needs to be on a background thread, particularly if it is lengthy or it will block your UI for the duration.